# Need to modify column concatenate VBA script to join selected columns only instead as well as to separate joined columns with a comma

Tags: excel, vba, automation, concatenation, textjoin

I need to take this code:

```
Sub ConcatColumns()

   Do While ActiveCell <> "" 


      ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
         ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) & " " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0)

      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
   Loop

End Sub
```

And I need to modify it so it will not only join two columns but up to 4, with the possibility of being able to choose which columns I want to concatenate. I also need the joined text to be separated by a comma and since this is Excel, I'm wondering if there's a way I can add some formatting if one of the columns is a date?

For example, manually I have to use this formula to make sure my dates are formatted as mm/dd/yyyy when using TEXTJOIN:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(I4="","",(TEXT(I4,"mm/dd/yyyy"))),IF(J4="","",(TEXT(J4,"mm/dd/yyyy"))),IF(K4="","",(TEXT(K4,"mm/dd/yyyy"))))
```

This is how my data looks:

Raw Data
[image]

This can go on with up to 5-10 other sets of ID's with their dates.

This is the result I need and what I'm having to do now do with =TEXTJOIN:

[image]

As you can see the dates don't come over formatted, even when I try to do it with the dropdown so I have to add some =TEXT formatting with the formula I pasted above.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to use VBA to write a formula?

Comment: I guess it doesn't have to be VBA as long as it does what it's supposed to? The most annoying thing is the date formatting and that sometimes I have to TEXTJOIN 5-6 times for different sets of columns so I would like to automate that.

Comment: The question is if you need a formula (that is evaluated by Excel every time that the content of the cells changes) or if it sufficient to set the result once (using pure VBA)

Comment: My data is set without any formulas. I wanted to use a VBA macro to use instead of the formula I'm having to use every time to join+format the dates.

Comment: Modifying your code above to join two or more columns is straightforward. What's not clear is the logic for your solution is to when you want two columns concatenated, or three, or four. Which column has the date field? How exactly do you want to choose which columns to concatenate?

Comment: Apologies for being confusing. I have added some images and further explanation to my original post that will probably help in understanding better. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach.  It will concatenate selection cell contents in the order the cells/ranges were selected (luckily Excel keeps track of this when you make a multi-area selection).  Result goes in the last-selected cell.

```vb
'When multiple cells in a row are selected, join the values from those cells with a comma,
'   and place the result in the last-selected cell
Sub JoinCells()
    Dim sel As Range, area As Range, c As Range, cDest As Range
    Dim addr As String, txt As String, sep As String, v

    Set sel = Selection

    'check that at least 3 cells are in the same row are selected...
    If sel.EntireRow.Cells.CountLarge > Rows(1).Count Or sel.Cells.Count < 3 Then
        MsgBox "Select at least 3 cells on the same row.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Do While Application.CountA(sel) > 0           'while any data in selected cells
        Set cDest = sel.Areas(sel.Areas.Count)     'last area selected
        Set cDest = cDest.Cells(cDest.Cells.Count) 'the last cell in that area is where the result goes
        addr = cDest.Address
        txt = ""    'reset result
        sep = ""    'reset separator
        For Each area In sel.Areas         'loop selected areas
            For Each c In area.Cells       'then cells within areas
                If c.Address <> addr Then  'not the "result" cell?
                    v = c.Value
                    If Len(v) > 0 Then     'any value to add?
                        txt = txt & sep & IIf(IsDate(v), Format(v, "mm/dd/yyyy"), v)
                        sep = ","          'add separator after first value
                    End If
                End If
            Next c
        Next area
        cDest.Value = txt       'populate the last selected cell
        Set sel = sel.Offset(1) 'next row down
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

Example: cells on row 3 were selected in the order shown while holding down Ctrl key. Make sure to select an empty cell last as the destination for the result.
**Note:** the macro will step down through the rows below as long as they have content, so only select cells on the first row of the data you want to work on.

[image]

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to do this, this is a really good approach for what I need and I think it could work perfectly. However I think I should have added some visuals the same way you did with my data so you have a better understanding of what I'm dealing with. I have now added those to my original post. Raw Data being: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbEvR.png] and my wanted result being: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7RZv.png]. Note that the dates have no formatting in the picture, but I do need them to which you already added to the script. Thank you so much again!

Comment: The above approach would work for you but you'd need to do it in 3 steps...

Comment: Do you mean 3 rows per running the macro?

Comment: No I mean select all the ID cells on the first row, and then the cell where you want those to be placed after concatenation.  Run the macro, then follow the same process for Eff Date, and then Exp Date

Comment: Thank you! I tried running it and it's erroring out here https://imgur.com/DH0XvjT

Comment: This is what happens when I run it on the ID columns using ctrl then select an empty cell to the right: https://imgur.com/undefined

Comment: That's not a working link...

Comment: https://imgur.com/fqpf2xi

Comment: Only select the cells on the first row - it will step down through the rows as long as there's data. I did make an edit to the code in my answer, under `'check that at least 3 cells are in the same row are selected...` which maybe you didn't catch. That would notify you about only selecting cells on one row.